# Can I "queue" XMLHttpRequest functions?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I need to get a list of available files (stored in a directory) and processed files (stored in a database table).

I have some JavaScript that calls a Python script and parses its (JSON) output into an object. This works nicely whether the Python is dealing with directory files or a database table.

```
function runGetList() {
    // request external Python script (output in JSON)
    var handleResponse = function(status, response) {
        // save JSON-from-Python as an object
        var jsonMDBList = xhr.response;
        // do stuff with the object data (build select box, build table)
    }
    var handleStateChange = function() {
        switch (xhr.readyState) {
            case 0: break; // uninitialized
            case 1: break; // loading
            case 2: break; // loaded
            case 3: break; // interactive
            case 4: // completed
                handleResponse(xhr.status, xhr.response);
                break;
            default: alert("unspecified error");
        }
    }
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
    xhr.open("GET", "python/GetListMDBs.py", true);
    xhr.responseType = "json";
    xhr.send();
}
```

However, I've now reached a point where I'm going to have multiple objects (e.g. one from `GetListMDBs.py`, one from `GetTable.py`) and list them in different parts of the final HTML. My initial thought was to make `runGetList()` into a general function that can be called with a parameter for the particular Python script I need.

```
function getAllLists() {
    var mdbListAll = runGetList('GetListMDBs.py');
    console.log("list mdbs: " + mdbListAll);
    var mdbListTbl = runGetList('GetTable.py');
    console.log("table mdbs: " + mdbListAll);
}
function runGetList(filename) {
    // etc.
}
```

This is correctly executing and getting objects from the individual Python scripts. But the `getAllLists()` function doesn't wait for that `return`ed object, it just keeps going and logs `list mdbs: undefined`.

**What can I change in my approach, so the script waits for each HTTP request to finish before moving to the next one (and doing stuff with the output)?** The only workaround I have thought of is a larger, more complex JSON object that has *all* the lists I want embedded, but I would prefer not to do that because those Python scripts are used by a few applications and I'm trying to keep it streamlined rather than replicating code all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Promise`

```
   function runGetList() {
     var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       // request external Python script (output in JSON)
       var handleResponse = function(status, response) {
         // save JSON-from-Python as an object
         var jsonMDBList = xhr.response;
         // do stuff with the object data (build select box, build table)
         resolve(jsonMDBList)
       }
       var handleStateChange = function() {
         switch (xhr.readyState) {
           case 0:
             break; // uninitialized
           case 1:
             break; // loading
           case 2:
             break; // loaded
           case 3:
             break; // interactive
           case 4: // completed
             handleResponse(xhr.status, xhr.response);
             break;
           default:
             alert("unspecified error");
         }
       }
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.onreadystatechange = handleStateChange;
       xhr.open("GET", "python/GetListMDBs.py", true);
       xhr.responseType = "json";
       xhr.send();
     });
     return p
   }

   function getAllLists() {
     var mdbListAll = runGetList('GetListMDBs.py');
     var mdbListTbl;
     console.log("list mdbs: " + mdbListAll);
     mdbListAll.then(function(data) {
       console.log("table mdbs: " + data);
       mdbListTbl = runGetList('GetTable.py');
       return mdbListTbl
     })
   }
```

Comment: `Promise` works, but I needed to tweak the calls. I tried to edit your answer but it was rejected as "deviating from the original intent" :P

Answer (score 1):

Based off [the answer from guest271314](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34726126/2118067) but with better chaining of asynchronous requests:

```
function runGetList(filename) {
    var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // do stuff to get jsonMDBList
        resolve(jsonMDBList)
    }};
    return p;
}

function getAllLists() {
    var mdbListAll = runGetList('GetListMDBs.py'); // returns promise 1
    mdbListAll.then(function(data) {               // runs when promise 1 resolves
        console.log("list mdbs: " + data);
        mdbListTbl = runGetList('GetTable.py');    // returns promise 2
        return mdbListTbl
    }).then(function(data) {                       // runs when promise 2 resolves
        console.log("table mdbs: " + data);
    });
}
```